# Python IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, how to enter model directory

Tags: python, ioerror

My file system is:

```
main.py
method
  |- __init__.py
  |- a.txt
  |- method.py
```

method.py is:

```
def method():
with open('a.txt') as f:
    print f.readlines()
```

main.py is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from method.method import method as meth
    meth()
```

When I run the main.py, IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.txt'.

I find the run directory is not in ./method/, so it find not the 'a.txt', how to solve it?

Thank u! :D

Comment: Where is your run directory then? You need to be in the same directory as `a.txt'

Comment: You should be doing `with open('method/a.txt') as f:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
import os
full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
file_path = '%s/a.txt' % os.path.dirname(full_path) 
def method():
  with open(file_path) as f:
    print f.readlines()
```